# How to display empty required input field in Razr

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model that contains some ints. One has a default value and the other does not. I would like to render the input fields with a value 4 for `A` and an empty value for `B`. It seems Razr automagically set the default to 0 for my `B`.

**The model**

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int A { get; set; } = 4;
  public int B { get; set; };
}
```

**The controller**

```
// GET /MyModel/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var myModel = new MyModel();
  return View(myModel );
}
```

**The create view**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.A, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.B, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

`A` renders fine as a 4 but `B` renders as 0.

I have tried passing `@value = ""` in the attributes to the editor for `B` but it still renders as 0.

How can I render `B` as an empty field? I do not want to make it nullable since it is a required field.

Comment: The default value for an int  = 0. If you want it to be *not set* make `B` nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `int` cannot be `null`. If you want to initially display a `null` (empty) value, but make it required, make the property `int?` and add a `[Required]` attribute

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
public int? B { get; set; };
```

and in the view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.B, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.B)
```